# how to prove this inequality using the muirhead inequality

Tags: inequality

How to prove the below inequality using the Muirhead:

$x^2y +x^2z + y^2z + y^2x + z^2x + z^2y \geq 6xyz$

I know the $(2,1,0)$ majorizes $(1,1,1)$ but then don't you get $xyz$  on the RHS as there is only one permutation of $1,1,1.$

Where does the 6 coefficient on the RHS come from?

Comment: are the variables positive?

Answer (score 1):

The permutations applied to xyz each give xyz which is why there is 6xyz on the right-hand side.

Comment: if the variables are not negative it is $AM-GM$